# transferred laravel from godaddy to hostgator and routes don't seem to work

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

laravel was working fine when I am hosting with GoDaddy but recently I transferred my domain to hostgator *first time on hostgator* and so I moved all laravel contents from GoDaddy to Hostgator by downloading everything from ftp then transferred all files over.  Database with godaddy and hostgator are different and so I created database in hostgator and implement everything needed but somehow when I load up my page in hostgator my page loads but when I click on any of the links in the page I keep on getting the 404.html.

At first I thought it was because my database info isn't set correctly because it's my first using using hostgator and their database uses localhost instead of like GoDaddy it has an ip for me to use as a host.

Anyways then I uploaded some other things into hostgator which isn't using laravel just normal php with database info and this works fine.  So now I am confused if it is because of laravel or it is hostgator? I have no idea where to start looking for what the problem is

*I was told by hostgator that they can migrate contents at a charge and everything will work perfectly the same as it was with godaddy but I figured this is a time I can learn if anything happens*

I am sorry if this a stupid question.  Can someone please give me a hand?  Thanks a lot

my folder structure

```
-root
   -public_html
      -user-login (laravel folder)
```

P.S. I have a free account with aws ec2 and I tried transferring all the files into aws-ec2 and I can see other pages fine just that let's say if I try to login it gives me errors which is normal since I didn't have database setup correctly but at least the links works

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure in hostgator?

Comment: I editted, not sure if this is what you meant Jerodev and when I go into the page I use `http://ip/myname/user-login/public` and then any link in it page goes to a 404.html but it was working totally fine in GoDaddy

Comment: Is it the Laravel 404 you get, or a 404 from hostgator? Do you have any error log on hostgator?

Comment: I believe it's 404 from hostgator because it has the hostgator logo and ummm...I am not sure about error log I just transferred over didn't touch anything except trying to import my stuffs >.<"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found out why and pretty much my stupidity I believe.
Somehow, as I said using hostgator (without a domain) I was loading the page using `http://ip/myname/laravel/public` and I can only see the index page any other links gives me error404.
I was still waiting for my domain transfer at that time so I had to load my page with my ip/username in order to load my pages.

Somehow after my domain is transferred and namespace is set in place.
For example my domain is www.domain.com after the transfer is complete and namespace is setup in hostgator now I can load the page as `http://www.domain.com/laravel/public` AH~ and all links are working fine as before.

*No idea what's the real reason behind this but after this, everything works like a charm now*

*If anyone has an idea the reason why, I wouldn't mind you posting / commenting here to gain my knowledge*

Comment: what do you mean by namespace is set in place?